# ubiqituious support for degenerate triangle strips across android devices?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm working with the opengl es 3.0 api for android. I'm writing functionality for a bitmap text renderer, and, well, it works flawlessly on two of my devices, both samsung. but on my kindle fire 10 HD (7th generation) tablet, it's all messed up. it's sampling from wrong portions of the texture atlas, displaying wrong glyphs, and it won't display the entire message sometimes, and sometimes when i go to switch messages, via mapped buffers, it briefly displays the entire message at once before starting the animation of it. Anyhow, I seem to think it's related to degenerate triangle strips that I'm using, so I ask, is support for them not ubiquitous across all android devices supporting opengl es 3.0? I've had trouble before with the kindle fire, in shader-related stuff. It won't work at all if I don't specify a precision, both for floats, and for sampler2DArray, that I've discovered thus far.

Answer (score 1):

A degenerate triangle "should just work"; there is no feature here in the API for the hardware not to support. They are just triangles which happen to have zero area because of two coincident vertices.

They have historically be really common for any content using triangle strips, so to be honest I'd be surprised if they are broken.

> It won't work at all if I don't specify a precision, both for floats, and for sampler2DArray, that I've discovered thus far.

That's not a bug; that's what the the specification requires you to do. See "4.7.4. Default Precision Qualifiers" in the OpenGL ES 3.2 shader language specification.